# Setting the initial state of a controlled input with a prop value that is initialized asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a controlled input that accepts a prop called `user`. This object is passed to it by its parent component, where it is initialized asynchronously with an observer<sup>1</sup>.

In the parent component:

```
onAuthStateChanged() {
  this.unregisterAuthObserver = onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    this.setState({
      isSignedIn: Boolean(user),
      user,
    });
  });
}
```

I would like to populate the initial state of the controlled input with `user.displayName`. Something like the following, which shouldn't be an anti-pattern because the state is only dependent on the prop `user` on construction.

```
class ControlledInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { user } = props;

    this.state = {
      displayName: user ? user.displayName : '',
    };
  }
}
```

When I refresh the controlled input, the following problem occurs:

1. The value of `user` is `undefined` because the observer has yet to fire. The component is constructed and `displayName` is assigned to `''`.
2. The observer fires, `user` is assigned a complex object, and React re-renders the component. This does not change the state of the component and `displayName` is still `''`.

I'm stuck on how to utilize the component lifecycle methods to achieve this. Is there a best practice for this scenario? Should I even be dependent on an asynchronous prop, or should I move the observer into the controlled component?

I've considered using `componentDidUpdate()` to determine when `user` is assigned, but it feels like a hack.

> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

---

<sup>1</sup> The observer is part of Firebase Authentication, but I'm not sure that's relevant to the question.

Comment: Why not add `displayName: user ? user.displayName : '',` to the state in `OnAuthStateChanged`?  `setState`?

Comment: Can you post your render function (actually the whole component)? How are you communicating the change to `user` down to `displayName`?

Comment: @ColinYoung That's done using a wrapper around a `Route` component from React Router: `<ProtectedRoute path="/controlledInput" render={() => <ControlledInput user={user} />} ... />`.

Comment: @JamesPoag I'm not sure that would solve the problem I'm having. The `displayName` would still be empty at the time the controlled input is constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to assign in the constructor. You should use the props provided to the render method, and following the [Lifting State Up pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) handle updates to the state in the parent. That will then flow down to the child component.

See the example below. The "increment" button simulates the async call. `ControlledInput` is a read-only display, while `ControlledInput2` allows edits to the input that are reflected in state.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.onInputChanged = this.onInputChanged.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      user,
      count: 1
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    const { user, count } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      user: { ...user, displayName: `display ${count + 1}` },
      count: count + 1
    });
  }

  onInputChanged(name) {
    this.setState({
      user: Object.assign(user, { displayName: name })
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { user, count } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <ControlledInput user={user} />
        <div>{user.displayName}</div>
        <div>Count: {count}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>increment</button>
        <div>
          <ControlledInput2 onInputChanged={this.onInputChanged} user={user} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ControlledInput = ({ user }) => 
  <input type="text" value={user.displayName} />;

class ControlledInput2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onInputChanged(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={user.displayName}
      />
    );
  }
}

const user = { displayName: undefined };

const props = { user };
const rootElement = document.getElementById("sample");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent {...props} />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample"></div>
```